# Linenumber of shebang line significant?

Tags: python, command-line-interface, shebang

I have a simple cli to convert timestamp to human readable datetime. For some reason, when I try to call it I invoke the `import` command from imagemagick instead.

```
> ts 1400029200000
Version: ImageMagick 6.8.7-7 Q16 x86_64 2013-11-27 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2014 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: DPC Modules
Delegates: bzlib freetype jng jpeg ltdl png xml zlib

Usage: import [options ...] [ file ]
```

Below is my script

```
1
2 #!/usr/bin/env python
3
4 import argparse
5 from datetime import datetime
6
...
12
16     time = args.time
...
22     print(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(time))
...
25
26 if __name__ == '__main__':
27     main()
28
```

When I move the shebang to the first line, I get the correct result

```
> ts 1400029200000
2014-05-14 01:00:00
```

What gives?

Comment: I believe so.  It tells the OS how to handle the script, so it's expected in the first line - otherwise you have to specify the shell when calling the script.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The 'shebang' must be the first line because it is interpreted by the kernel, which looks at the two bytes at the start of an executable file.

If these are `#!` the rest of the line is interpreted as the code to run and with the script file available to that program. At the moment you have a newline and *then* the characters in the line.

Comment: I see. Then if there is no shebang line, is the script by default executed as a bash script? If so, is there a way to change the default?

Comment: @KevinSLin I'm afraid I don't know, I'm not an active Linux user. You should ask a different question to get some expertise on that.

Comment: @KevinSLin If there is no shebang line (on the first line), then it is indeed executed by whatever shell you used to try running the command - in your case `bash`. [`import`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/import.php) is a program that is part of `imagemagick`.

Comment: You could make your shell /usr/bin/python, but you'd find that common shell tasks became substantially more difficult. Keep your shebangs on the first line.